# Optimal method for creating a 2D Array without any repetitions

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to create some code to fish out records from a list of about 200k to 1million records. Obviously, I would want this process to be as fast as possible. The basic idea is as follows, the records in the large list are a combination of numbers which are to be kept together. For Example:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,400076,400097,800076,800097
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200032,200078,500032,500078
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,300043,300083,600043,600083
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,600026,600077,900026,900077
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100008,100028,400028,400056,600008,600056
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,400042,400098,500042,500098
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,86,500015,500086
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,400013,400076,800013,800076
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,700024,700083,900024,900083
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100003,100047,800003,800047
```

The maximum length of the record is 20 which is why the additional zeroes. Let's not worry about these for a moment. So, I want to "fish" out some records such that no repetitions are observed. If one repetition is there, I can discard that record and no longer look at it further. Thus, I must compile a list which looks like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,400076,400097,800076,800097
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200032,200078,500032,500078
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,300043,300083,600043,600083
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,600026,600077,900026,900077
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100008,100028,400028,400056,600008,600056
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,400042,400098,500042,500098
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,86,500015,500086
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,700024,700083,900024,900083
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100003,100047,800003,800047
```

Note how in the above list, record no. 8 is missing because the number 400076 already exists in a previous record.

The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
void Make_List(ConfigList *pathgroups, ConfigList *configlist)
{
int i,j,k,l,flag,pg_num=0,len,p_num=0;
for(i = 0;i<configlist->num_total;i++)
{
    flag = 0;
    for(j = configlist->configsize-1;j>=0;j--)
    {   
        if(configlist->pathid[i][j])
        {
            for(k = 0;k<pg_num;k++)
            {
                for(l = pathgroups->configsize-1;l>=0;l--)
                {
                    if(pathgroups->pathid[k][l])
                    {
                        if(configlist->pathid[i][j]==pathgroups->pathid[k][l])
                        {
                            flag++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        len = 0;
        for(j = configlist->configsize-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            pathgroups->pathid[pg_num][j]=configlist->pathid[i][j];
            if(configlist->pathid[i][j])
            {
                len++;
            }
        }
        pg_num++;
        p_num+=len;
        if(p_num>=totpaths)
        {
            break;
        }
    }   
}
Print_ConfigList(stderr,pathgroups);
}
```

The structure ConfigList basically stores the 2D array along with other things used in different parts of the program.

`num_total` tells us the number of rows in the array whereas `configsize` tells us the number of columns in the array.

`totpaths` is a breakpoint which terminates the loop early in case assignment is completely finished.

Comment: @MBaas Apologies I should have mentioned. I'm using C

Comment: The biggest number I see is 900083.  What's the biggest number that's allowed?

Comment: @user3386109 99999999 is the biggest number allowed

Comment: Pablo beat me to it. Create an array of 100000000 bytes. Use `memset` to clear the array to 0. As you process records, set the byte corresponding to each number. That way it's easy to check which numbers have already been used.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not getting exactly what you're saying

Comment: The technique I suggest is to keep track of repeated numbers with an "in-use" array. I'll give you an example. Let's say you only had numbers from 0 to 9. You would start by declaring an array[10] and set every entry to 0. If the first record has 2 and 5, you set `array[2] = 1` and `array[5] = 1`. Now imagine the second record has 3 and 5. To figure out if 3 is a repeat check array[3]. It's 0, so 3 is not a repeat. However array[5] is 1, so 5 is a repeat, and you can discard the record. That's the general idea. If the largest number is 99999999, the in-use array needs to be 100000000 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if each element is repeated for each new element analyzed has a computational cost of `O(N^2)` which, given your large input set, is far too much.

Basically, what you need is a fast access data-structure where you can keep a count of how many times your record has appeared or at least a boolean flag.

The easiest way to do this is to have an array where the position represent each possible value and the array value the count of times the position value has appeared (or its boolean value of existence). However, if your data range is too large you can do this because the memory used to store the array is proportional to the range size.

The alternative to avoid that is to use Hash tables or sets.

As you has established in your comments above, your integer range is `[0,99999999]` so if you wanted to use a vector to keep track of the presence or not of each single value you would need approximately `96 MB` to store it in memory.

This is an example using byte arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_IN_RANGE 99999999

int main()
{

    char * isInInput = (char*)malloc(MAX_IN_RANGE+1);
    memset(isInInput,0,MAX_IN_RANGE+1);
    size_t i;
    int inputExample[] = {1,3,5,2,1,5};


    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int value = inputExample[i];
        printf("%d\n",value);
        if(!isInInput[value])
        {
            printf("Add value %d to your collection\n", value);
            isInInput[value] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is repeated\n", value);
        }
    }
    free(isInInput);
}
```

To use hash tables instead you can rely on libraries such as [Judy](http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/JudyHS_3x.htm) in order to avoid implementing your own hash table.

Comment: There a not a lot of numbers so I would love to do that. There about about 900 unique numbers but they range from 1 to 900099

Comment: I don't want to use hash tables because it would complicate things as I'm not aware of how to do so. I don't mind an array

Comment: @AdityaSomani If you can afford using 95-96 MB of memory you can avoid using HashTables. The problem with that is that, in order to access the value count in O(1), you need the value to be the array index so you need to reserve 100000000 array positions (one to each single value of your range). Yes, you me hayve only 900 unique numbers but you don't initially know which ones in the range are they.

Comment: Very important: `if (!isInInput[value]) isInInput[value] = 1;`

Comment: Using this technique on 500K records should speed things up by about a million times faster. That's pretty good, I say :)

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah! The drawback is the memory use :(

Comment: True, but using 100MB on modern machines that have multiple gigabytes of memory isn't all that bad.

Comment: @user3386109 I like to see this as a hash table where `hash_function(key) = key` and `size(table) = nelements(range)`

Comment: Yes, if the language was anything other than C, I would definitely go with the hash table. Whether it's worth the time to get a hash table working in C depends on how many times the OP expects to run this code.

Comment: PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo When I read this the first time around, I wasn't able to completely understand what you were talking about. Maybe in a fresher state of mind. I realize now that I have all the framework to implement what you mentioned. I actually have a way to translate back those integer numbers into the data storage. I am using to count their assignment. So I don't even need the large amount of memory you mentioned. All in all, I agree with @user3386109 and you that, this would make it a 1000 times faster. I'll try and implement it today. Thanks a ton to both of you. SO FTW! :)